# java multi level JPopupMenu

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, menu, jpopupmenu

I've created a JPopupMenu with two items (add,remove). I want "addItem" to have a sub popup menu. The hierarchy is like this:

```
add
  pizza
  cake
  ...
remove
```

my code:

```
JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();
menu.add(new JMenuItem("remove"));
JMenuItem addItem = new JMenuItem("add");
menu.add(addItem);

addItem.add(new JPopupMenu()); // it is not working for me
```

Once I move the mouse close to "add item", the menu disappears.
please help me to build this popup menu.

Comment: Add a `JMenu` instead of a `JPopupMenu`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `JMenu` (sub class of `JMenuItem`).

```
JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();
menu.add(new JMenuItem("remove"));
JMenuItem addItem = new JMenu("add");
menu.add(addItem);

addItem.add(new JMenuItem("pizza"));
addItem.add(new JMenuItem("cake"));
```

[image]